# Regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, string, text-parsing

i have text something like this.

> @@MMIVLoader@ProductVer@4.1.2@BCM_7400S_LE@Product@Aug 21 2009@
>   @@MMIVLib@ObjectVer@4.1.2@BCM_7400S_LE@Product@Aug 21 2009@
>   @@HuaweFGDLDrv@ObjectVer@01.00.09@7324@PRODUCT@Aug 20 2009@
>   @@ProtectVer@ObjectVer@127.8.1 @BCM_SDE5.03@PRODUCT@Aug  4 2009 06:56:19@
>   @@KernelSw@ObjectVer@0.0.1@BCM-7454@PRODUCT@ Dec 19 2007@
>   @@ReceiverSw@ObjectVer@E.5.6.001@HWBC01ZS@PRODUCT@May 3 2010@

i want the out put in an array like

```
MMIVLoader 4.1.2
MMIVLib         4.1.2
HuaweFGDLDrv 01.00.09
ProtectVer 127.8.1 
KernelSw 0.0.1
ReceiverSw E.5.6.001
```

Can any one suggest me how to do this in c# using regular expression or is there a any sophisticated way to do this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

This is easy, you can just split by `@` (removing the empty items) and pull the first and third items.

```
var list = myString.Split(new String[] {Environment.NewLine},
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)                
   .Select(item => item.Split(new char[] {'@'}, 
          StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   .Where(a => a.Length > 2)
   .Select(a => new { Item = a[0], Version = a[2] }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Beautiful. I was thinking about splitting it, but the extra @ annoyed me. `RmoveEmptyEntries` is a nice option.

Comment: how can we do this using regular expressions ?

Comment: @user340015 you're looking for problems? :-/

Answer (score 3):

Or simply remove extra stuff from line

```
Regex.Replace(text, @"^@@([^@]+)@[^@]+@([^@]+).*", "$1,$2",RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

to get

```
MMIVLoader,4.1.2
MMIVLib,4.1.2
HuaweFGDLDrv,01.00.09
ProtectVer,127.8.1
KernelSw,0.0.1
ReceiverSw,E.5.6.001
```

And then, just split by comma on each line to get array

Answer (score 2):

If you do want a crazy regex solution, you can use this:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(
    input,
    "@@(?<name>.*?)@(Product|Object)Ver@(?<ver>.*?)@",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups);

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", match["name"], match["ver"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is a LINQ version with query syntax :)

```
string[] lines = new string[] { 
            "@@MMIVLoader@ProductVer@4.1.2@BCM_7400S_LE@Product@Aug 21 2009@",
            "@@MMIVLib@ObjectVer@4.1.2@BCM_7400S_LE@Product@Aug 21 2009@",
            "@@HuaweFGDLDrv@ObjectVer@01.00.09@7324@PRODUCT@Aug 20 2009@",
            "@@ProtectVer@ObjectVer@127.8.1 @BCM_SDE5.03@PRODUCT@Aug  4 2009 06:56:19@",
            "@@KernelSw@ObjectVer@0.0.1@BCM-7454@PRODUCT@ Dec 19 2007@",
            "@@ReceiverSw@ObjectVer@E.5.6.001@HWBC01ZS@PRODUCT@May  3 2010@" };
var q = from components in
           (from line in lines
            select line.Split(new char[] { '@' }, 
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        select new { Name = components[0], Version = components[2] };
foreach (var item in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item: Name={0} Version={1}", item.Name, item.Version);
}
```

Comment: @ck: yeah I know.. I meant the query syntax. I'll rephrase